# Web Worker - importScripts "on finished" callback

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I use importScripts() to load huge JSON file (several dozens of MB) into webworker.

Is it possible to send callback when the import has been completed?

ex.  self.postMessage("finished")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes a little late but it seems that you can post a message to your worker right after you new it. Once it calls back, it means that the worker JavaScript file and its children are all fully loaded as importScripts is a synchronous call.

You can have a look at that:
http://pierre.palatin.fr/entries/javascript-web-workers